# "NpgsqlCommand" не содержит определения "LastInsertedId" и "NpgsqlDataReader" - "GetUInt32"

Tags: c#, sql, postgresql, mariadb

"NpgsqlCommand" не содержит определения "LastInsertedId", и не удалось найти доступный метод расширения "LastInsertedId", принимающий тип "NpgsqlCommand" в качестве первого аргумента (возможно, пропущена директива using или ссылка на сборку).

```
connection.Open();
NpgsqlCommand command = connection.CreateCommand();
command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO users (name) VALUES (@playerName)";
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@playerName", playerModel.realName);
command.ExecuteNonQuery();

playerId = (int)command.LastInsertedId;
```

"NpgsqlDataReader" не содержит определения "GetUInt32", и не удалось найти доступный метод расширения "GetUInt32", принимающий тип "NpgsqlDataReader" в качестве первого аргумента (возможно, пропущена директива using или ссылка на сборку)

```
reader.GetUInt32("text");
```

До этого был MariaDB переделываю под PostgreSQL, как это можно исправить=)

Answer (score 0):

```
command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO users (name) VALUES (@playerName) RETURNING id";
playerId = (int)command.ExecuteScalar();
```

а также:

```
(uint)reader.GetInt32("text");
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]